# Mysql database design for customer multiple addresses and default address

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, e-commerce

I am creating the database structure of an ecommerce with Mysql and INNODB engine.

**Point 1**: To create multiple addresses for the customers i have this tables

[image]

Am I doing it in the correct way? And how should I store the default address (in which table)?

**Point 2**: I have another table called "Suppliers", should i just connect it to addresses with a "supplier_address" table or is there a better way?

**Point 3**: What about the tables cities and countries? Should i add something or is that ok? Maybe a field "district" in another table beetween the two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my view you're making this far too complex. There's no need to make your address schema so over-normalized.  Most systems I've seen that handle multiple customer addresses have a customer table like yours, and then have an address table, as follows:

```
 customer_id
 address_ordinal  (small number for each customer: 0,1,2,3 etc).
 primary    (boolean)
 address_1
 address_2
 locality   (city, village, etc)
 province   (state, etc)
 postcode   (zip, postcode etc)
 country
```

`customer_id` is a foreign key to the `customer` table. The primary key is a composite of (`customer_id`, `address_ordinal`).  The `primary` column is `true` if the address is the primary one.

Regarding your question about suppliers, you might want to create a common table called "contacts", and give both your customers and suppliers contact_ids.

If your system contains a reference table (perhaps something you purchase from a data supplier) containing (postcode, locality, province) rows, you can use that to help populate your address table. But you should avoid forcing your addresses to only contain hard-coded postcodes: those reference tables get out of date very fast.

Comment: For what do you insert the field address_ordinal? And what if the addresses are in different cities, maybe in different province, and have different postcodes?

Comment: It's possible for some addresses to have two lines (e.g. 1120 Park Avenue / Apartment 102). That's why there are `address_1` and `address_2` columns. If a particular customer_id has just one address, the ordinal is 0. If you add another, the ordinal will be 1, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start out my answer with the ole cliche: "There's more than one way to skin a cat." That said, I have a few suggestions:

Point 1 - Assuming a customer can have multiple addresses (i.e. billing and mailing), then yes, you have the right idea in terms of the separate mapping table. As for adding a field to customer_addresses called default or preferred, or something like that, it's not a bad idea, but another option is to add a new field called address_type that would reference a separate table with two records, "Billing" and "Mailing" and/or whatever else you would want. Then, in whatever application you are coding that is going to use the address data, depending on what context i.e. if you're on the billing info page, then code the address type that you use on the page itself something like `SELECT * FROM customer_addresses WHERE address_type = 2 /* Billing */`.

Point 2 - Same as for customers.

Point 3 - Do you want to be able to display shortened country names? For example, abbreviate "United States" to "US," "Canada" to "CAN," or "United Kingdom" to "UK?" I'd consider adding a field for abbreviated country names for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks! Some questions: in point 1, if the customers wants change the default address, i should then modify that field, but what if there is an error while doing that? i'll have an user without a default address for example? I think that is inconsistent, maybe would it be better adding this field in the customer table?

Comment: Maybe thinking about it, the second option you said is better, so the user can store one addr for billing and one for shipping ;) I colud also add for example type 3, that indicates an address added by the customer that actually isn't used for billing or shipping! what do you think about it?