# efficient Db Design with (many to many plus one to manys)

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

(revised) I have a web app where information will be entered for a user. First and last name as well as 3 Affiliations (primary, secondary, and tertiary) associated with the person. Each affiliation has 3 components (title, department, and university). So for example one record could be for:

User: Bob, Robertson

Affiliation1: Professor, Chemistry, U. Florida

Affiliation2: Director, Amazing Chemistry Institute, U. Florida

Affiliation3: Affiliated Faculty, BioChemistry, Florida Tech.

Also, Title and Department are text input fields but Univ. refers to a specific list of about 3000 university names 'univ_name' which is why it has it's own table. also affiliationOrdinal would be something like (1st, 2nd, 3rd)

```
Users         Affiliation           Univ.
=======      ============         =========  
id_user      id_affiliation        id_univ     
FirstName    id_user              univ_name
LastName     affiliationOrdinal              
             title
             department
             id_univ
```

Thanks Sean for your feedback, I started thinking of this more as a user with multiple addresess type of problem and that has been solved many times over it seems. I picked this one as a reference. [Mysql database design for customer multiple addresses and default address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081123/mysql-database-design-for-customer-multiple-addresses-and-default-address). So the above should be a bit closer to workable right?

Comment: I would create an Affiliation table with 4 columns (id_user, id_title, id_dept, id_univ). And I don't at all understand what the numbered columns are here but those are a big red flag that you need to normalize those.

Comment: Okay, I think with the affiliation table I wouldn't need the numbered columns. But instead of having id_univ shouldn't i have Id_univ_BG in there? On the other hand since I would have the affiliation table essentially serving as a bridge I could also just do away with the univ_bridge table right?

Comment: This might warrant a separate question but what would be a good approach for posting to the db (creating records)? I already have the id_user as a variable using select scope_identity() when I enter FirstName and LastName into the Users table. would I then go through the title, depts, and univ, tables making inserts and saving the ids which would at the end be posted into the affiliation table?

Comment: I don't know which column would be best because I only have a list of names here. There certainly seems to be some serious normalization issues going on here. I honestly don't get what the Univ_Bridge table is for. It looks like might be partially handling a many to many?

Comment: I couldn't begin to tell you how to populate this because I have no details to work with...and the tables need to be fixed first.

Comment: Okay, one last fix then it appears to work. Not sure if it is the most efficient but... since I use a jquery autocomplete from the university list to populate my univ1 univ2 and univ3 fields I don't even need to use the id_univ in the affiliation table. I can just post the name retrieved from the autocomplete and post it to the table.